# SharedPreferences disappear when killing app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make an app with accounts, but I'm struggling with `SharedPrefences`. I made them save the account name, and it works, but only when I kill app once, I can turn off the phone and get it back on, and it's still there, but when I kill the app with saved preferences for 3/4 times, all accounts are gone. What is the problem, I save preferences with `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onStop` and read with `onResume`, `onCreate`, onRestart. Before I had only the onPause and onResume and it worked the same. Here is the code :

```
   @Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putString("uzytkownik1", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik2", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz2"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik3", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz3"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik4", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz4"));
    editor.putString("haslo1", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy1"));
    editor.putString("haslo2", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy2"));
    editor.putString("haslo3", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy3"));
    editor.putString("haslo4", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy4"));
    editor.apply();
}
```

And I wrote the same in onStop and onDestroy.

onResume:

```
        sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik1", null) != null || sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik2", null) != null || sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik3", null) != null || sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik4", null) != null) {
        user1.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik1", null));
        user2.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik2", null));
        user3.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik3", null));
        user4.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik4", null));
```

and the same in `onCreate`, and `onRestart`.

Comment: What values are you getting from `getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz")`? I hope these are not null. You can check the values by keeping `logs`.
`SharedPreferences` never get cleared when app is killed.

Comment: Logins of users, when they create account in another activity, from editext view.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing `super.onPause();` after you've set `SharedPreferences`

Like this

```
@Override 
protected void onPause(){ 
    sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putString("uzytkownik1", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik2", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz2"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik3", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz3"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik4", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz4"));
    editor.putString("haslo1", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy1"));
    editor.putString("haslo2", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy2"));
    editor.putString("haslo3", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy3"));
    editor.putString("haslo4", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy4"));
    editor.apply(); 

    super.onPause(); 

}
```

Comment: Still disappears, I think that the problem may be that I get the values from editext in another activity, and it get's cleared when i kill the app. Should I transfer the values from the other activity with shared pref, not the intent putExtra?

Answer (score 0):

Use editor.commit() instead of apply().

according to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()):

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
>   this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
>   still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
>   completed as well as the commit itself.

when in onPause method you call apply() it will try to write data asynchronously but the thread will kill instantly before writing it in sharedprefs. you can replace your code with this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putString("uzytkownik1", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik2", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz2"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik3", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz3"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik4", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz4"));
    editor.putString("haslo1", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy1"));
    editor.putString("haslo2", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy2"));
    editor.putString("haslo3", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy3"));
    editor.putString("haslo4", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy4"));
    editor.commit();

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: This is true, but the user is leaving the app, there is no need to get a response. Since the user is leaving the application, preferences doesn't need to stay alive. This is only necessary when calling multiple instances of `SharedPreferences` and you want to make sure the previous call finishes successfully before calling another instance of `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Still disappears, I think that the problem may be that I get the values from editext in another activity, and it get's cleared when i kill the app. Should I transfer the values from the other activity with shared pref, not the intent putExtra?

Comment: @PiotrekSzkudi are you sure onPause is calling? check it with logging and also check the value of strings. I dont think putExtra is the problem.

Comment: Should i only use onPause or onDestroy and onStop? And where should i call it back? OnResume, onCreate?

Comment: this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) may help you for better understanding lilfecyle of activity.